# save id instead of name in datalist in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I want to show name in datalist options and get id of that one and if it is not in database then add in database and gets it's id.

my view

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="bmd-label-floating" name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" list="name" />
     <datalist id="name">
       @foreach($data $data)
         <option>{{$data->name}}</option>
       @endforeach
     </datalist>
 </div>
```

and if I use option like that

```
<option value={{$data->id}}>{{$data->name}}</option>
```

then in view it return me like that 1-roger 2-alex which look awkward

it return me name but I need it's id

Comment: @foreach($data as $datum)    <option value="{{$datum->id}}">{{$datum->name}}</option>

Answer (score 1):

You should put double quotes on value.

```
<option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
```

And you shouldn't use the same variable name for both array and its item.

```
@foreach($data as $item)
    <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```